# Two-verb compounds: 振る舞う: plain-form + plain-form verb instead of masu-form + plain form?

Tags: verbs

I finished Core 10000 (an Anki deck) and 振る舞う (to entertain) was one of the last ones to pop up.

I find it interesting because to me it appears to be a combination of plain form 振る (to shake) + another plain form verb 舞う (to dance). This differs from all the other two-verb compounds I am used to such as 取り引き (transaction, noun in this case)、書き直す (rewrite)、やり直す (redo)、吹き出す (blow out), 話し出す (start talking)、飛び上がる (fly up), where the first verb is the masu-form instead of plain.

I cannot recall any similar plain-form + plain-form verbs like 振る舞う.

My theory is that either this verb is an exception to the rule or this verb is in fact, NOT a two-verb compound. It is simply ふるまう, a single verb, and the Kanji was conveniently added later to make it look like a two-Kanji compound.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, linking two verb in their 連体形 ("dictionary") form is unusual and unexpected.

Both of the dictionaries 日本国語大辞典 and 広辞苑 suggest the following explanation:

> 「観智院本名義抄」や「色葉字類抄」で「翔」を「ふるまふ」と読んでいることから「羽を存分に振って自由舞う」という「振るい舞う」が原義かとおもわれる。

That is, it is a shortening of the original form *huruimau*, in the sense of a bird flapping its wings and taking flight, fluttering about in the skies (= "dancing", the Japanese *mau* is used in this sense). *hurui* is the 連用形 ("masu-stem") of the verb *huruu*, and this explanation would render the compound regular.

However, both dictionaries imply that this is only a hypothesis, and a dictionaries main purpose is not to list etymological research. It is just as well that the kanji are simple *ateji* and that *hurumau* derives from some different word(s), or that it is simply irregular. The earliest usage a quick dictionary lookup yields is from about 800 years ago, in the 古今著聞集.

Comment: Trying to answer old and unanswered questions. Feel free to add your answer if you have got some more insight.